# ESD damage after touching metal PC case?

Tags: esd, ground-plane, motherboard, cases, static-electricity

When i'm tribocharged and then discharge to a graphics card, i can kill that device.

[image]

Let's say i'm at -2000V, compared to my motherboard, and i touch the metal traces around the board's screw holes. Then, i guess, i'll donate a significant amount of electrons into the board, almost instantly. This could definitely harm the board.

But... let's consider my desktop PC. All cables are disconnected. I can touch the unpainted backside and by doing so i discharge myself to components inside the case, because: hard link between case and motherboard's ground-plane. After doing so, my PC doesn't seem to be damaged.

**Is there no damage? Could i expect latent failure? Was there too little charge on my body?** I would really like to understand this.

The metal PC case isn't a Faraday case, because the motherboard is hard linked to the case. Via conductive standoffs.

Comment: Touching the case ground is the right thing to do so that any potential difference is safely shunted thru the case and not into sensitive pins.

Comment: But, when i donate electrons to the case, then i'm also donating electrons into the motherboard, right? Because case and motherboard's ground-plane are always at the same potential, via brass standoffs.

Comment: The voltage drop and current discharge in on the finger and case not between case and motherboard.

Comment: Be aware that even if you zap a grounded case or other object that is not connected to the board, you will still generate electrostatic radiation that could still damage the components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first have to understand **what** is damaged by static discharge.

It's a MOS transistors' gate electrode insulation layer. That layer is so thin it breaks through at 5..20V applied to it against source or drain, and the minimal currents of a static discharge are enough to create a conductible path through it. Which, in result, fries the device as soon real power is applied.

That's why you cannot fry your computer by touching the casing. Because there are no MOS gates connected to it. It simply makes no sense to connect the gate contact to the ground level of the circuit in a PC. You can, however, still fry it by touching a badly designed interface connector.

Comment: Thanks. Is the MOSFET not connected to the motherboard's ground-plane?

Comment: Not the gate electrode, which is the only ESD sensitive part of it.

Comment: And this is why you should use an ESD strap as well.. The 1MR will allow you to safely discharge

Comment: The only ESD sensitive part of any MOS transistor.

Comment: @Janka Thanks. When i'm charged negatively and i touch the metal traces around the motherboard's screw holes, i'm actually donating electrons into the motherboard. Then, what happens precisely? Where do these electrons go? Into the ICs?

Comment: Touching the ground plane, you can't damage anything by ESD. The electrons go into the ICs, but not at the gate contact of any MOS transistor, only at source contacts. And these aren't ESD sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

When you touch a metal chassis around mounting holes of your mainboard, the charge you "donate" will flow into chassis ground, which is connected to Earth ground of your environment and dissipate. So your guess that "it will definitely harm the board" is not founded, because the ESD impulse is not going through vital sensitive semiconductor junction, unless the discharge misses the mounting hole and goes into some IC pin directly. But you are not supposed to charge yourself and then discharge into naked open computer: you either need to have an anti-static wrist, or the computer must be enclosed to manufacturer's specification, so the discharge can go only into system shield.

When you discharge yourself into a disconnected and not charged object as a standalone laptop, the "donated electrons" also flow into laptop chassis through exposed metal SHIELDS. But, instead of sinking into Earth ground, the charge will be simply re-distributed between your body and the laptop body. So the discharge will also occur, but maybe only at half or less, depending on proportion between effective capacitance of two bodies. It still does not make much of a difference in any case, grounded mainboard chassis, or floating laptop.

Could you expect latent failure in open mainboard case? Yes, for sure, since you don't control where the ESD strikes.

Should you expect latent failures in enclosed laptop case? Likely no, because the laptop is designed with only exposed parts that are connected to its chassis, and the sensitive electronics is effectively in a Faraday cage. And the ESD can go only into its shield, by means of mechanical design of its exposed connectors.

ILLUSTRATION of possible path of ESD in event of discharging into internal mounting point: [image] Voltage drop across finite resistances R of chassis and signal ground causes added voltage at points A and B, possibly exceeding breakdown thresholds of CMOS gates at the circuit inputs.

Comment: Thanks! But, looking at a desktop, are the desktop case and the motherboard's ground-plane not just the same thing, from an electrical standpoint? They are always at the same potential. I guess, the charge will be distributed between my body and the desktop case ánd the motherboard ánd components installed onto the motherboard. So, i will be donating electrons into the motherboard. Since, in this case, there is no resistance in between, electrons can enter the motherboard almost instantly... ESD?

Comment: There is always some resistance, even in metal frame, and between mounting holes. If you apply a capacitor charged to 2 kV to a 20 mOhm, there will be still a (short) pulse of 2-kV amplitude. While most electrons "enter" the metal chassis, some will spike through signal ground of the board, and there could be momentary voltage difference between different connected ICs. It is all complicated. To get the general idea, you need to draw an approximate equivalent diagram of all your interconnected grounds with realistic impedances, and solve Kirchhoff's equations around the applied ESD.

Answer (score 0):

The insides of a computer need no charge flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1STW5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>